# I have installed node-red on my raspberry pi but it does not start

Tags: nodered

I installed node-red but the `node-red-start` command does not work. 
I get this error:

`-bash: node-red-start: command not found`

This was an old pi that I recently upgraded from wheezy to Jessie.  The GUI interface also does not show node-red in the programming section.  What should I check?

Answer (score 2):

If it is not shown in the GUI interface, it is possible that it was not installed properly, or at all. Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodered
```

Then try running `node-red-start`

Comment: thanks Patrick - there was a problem with my install.  In fact, I had several issues because it seems my attempt to upgrade from wheezy to jessie never really did the trick.  I finally burned a new SD with Jessie and rebooted then I was able to install node-red successfully.